# App crashes on iOS simulator when forced to Sign In With Apple ID

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, ios-simulator

I have been testing my app successfully for months now. Within the last week when I launch my app on the simulator I get a "Sign In With Apple ID" prompt. Whether I cancel or sign in successfully it closes my app and Android Studio loses connection to the app and posts the following:

> Unsupported value: Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=2 "An unknown error occurred. Please try again." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred. Please try again.} of type NSError

- I have tried different OS versions in the simulator
- The app works fine and normally in on a real device (Android and iOS)
- OSX, Xcode, Android Studio, Flutter are all up to date

Does anyone know what's going on here and how I can help it?

[image: screenshot of apple auth in simulator]
[image: screenshot of apple bug reporting popup]

Comment: Sign In with Apple is not working on Simulator, it's a common known issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this, but I think you may be misunderstanding. It's not an Apple Sign In feature in the app (I'm aware of that bug). The issue I'm having seems almost like the simulator is requiring an apple sign in for me to test the app. The same issue occurs whether I'm signed into the device with my apple account or not

Comment: FYI It looks like the crash was happening when trying to restore purchases with the In App Purchases package. This was working previously so some update introduced the issue.I'm bypassing the restore purchases method when on simulators for now

Comment: @u2tall Thanks for the hint about restoring purchases, I had the same error.